# What is the result of $\lg^35+\lg^320+\lg8\lg0.25$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

$$\lg^35+\lg^320+\lg8\lg0.25=$$

I tried this
$$(\lg(5)+\lg(20))*[\lg^2(5)+\lg(2)*\lg(5) + \lg^2(2)]+3\lg(2)*(-2\lg(2))=$$

$$\lg(100)*[\lg^2(5)+\lg(2)*\lg(5) + \lg^2(2)]-6*\lg^2(2)=$$

Comment: What means $\lg^3(5)$ is this $(\lg(5))^3$?

Comment: and $\lg(x)=\log_{10}(x)$?

Comment: Most times that I encounter notation like that, $\log^3(5)=\log(\log(\log(5)))$.  Such notation comes up frequently in combinatorics.  As for what base the log should be, your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: I think it is $\lg^3(x)=(\lg(x))^3$

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner yes

Comment: According to Wolfram Alpha lg_3(5)+lg_3(20)+lg(8)*lg(0.25)=3.648092 =912023/250000

Comment: If you truly intend $\log^3(x)$ to be interpreted as $(\log(x))^3$ instead of as $\log(\log(\log(x)))$, then write it that way.  Less than common notations are used in order to *shorten* expressions which are otherwise long.  Writing $\log^3(x)$ instead of $(\log(x))^3$ is hardly shorter and instead confuses people who are used to seeing the other notation.  Avoid that notation at all costs in the future.

Comment: The base of $\lg(x)$ is the $10$

Comment: @JMoravitz ok, thank you for your suggestion

Comment: @Camelia, Always try to covert the expressions inside log such that they are in multiples or exponents of the base. In this case, try converting them in multiples/exponents of 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}\log^3(5)+\log^3(20)+\log 8 \log 0.25 & = \log^3\left(\dfrac{10}{2}\right)+\log^3(10\cdot 2) + \log 2^3\log 2^{-2} \\ & = (1-\log 2)^3 + (1+\log 2)^3 -6(\log 2)^2 \\ & = 1-3\log 2+3\log^2 2-\log^3 2+1+3\log 2 + 3\log^2 2 + \log^3 2 - 6\log^2 2 \\ & = 2\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:$(\lg(5))^3+(\lg(20))^3=(\lg(5)+\lg(20)((\lg(5))^2-\lg(5)\lg(20)+(\lg(20))^2)$
and

$$\lg(5)+\lg(20)=\lg(100)=2$$
and $$\lg(8)=3\lg(2)$$
and
$$\lg(0.25)=\lg(4^{-1})=\lg(2^{-2})=-2\lg(2)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$(\log{5}+\log{20})^3-3(\log{20})(\log{5})(\log{5}+\log{20})+\log{8}\log{\frac{1}{4}}$$

$$(\log{\frac{10}{2}}+\log{10*2})^3-3(\log{10*2})(\log{\frac{10}{2}})(\log{\frac{10}{2}}+\log{10*2})+\log{2^3}\log{2^{-2}}$$

$$(2)^3-3((\log{10})^2-(\log{2})^2)(2)-6(\log{2})^2$$

$$8-6$$

$$2$$